# Finding the optimal strategy of a stock trading game

Tags: stochastic-processes, geometric-brownian

Assume there is a stock, its price at time $t$ is $S(t)$. Its price is changing according to a geometric brownian motion, that is $dS=S(\mu dt+\sigma dW)$. You start with $\\\$1$ and you are allowed to choose a fraction $f$ amout of your net worth to put into the stock at any given time. After a period of time $T$, if your net worth is greater than $\\\$e$, you win, otherwise you lose. What strategy should you choose to maximise the probability of winning? (A strategy is a function that inputs the current wealth, the remaining time until $T$, and outputs the fraction $f$).

Let the wealth at time $t$ be $N(t)$, for a given strategy $f$, the change of wealth $dN(t)=f(N(t),T-t)N(t)(\mu dt+\sigma dW)$

A simpler version of this question would be asking for a fixed $f$ for all time (instead of a function of time). This will gives $dN(t)=fN(t)(\mu dt+\sigma dW)$, which means $N(T)$~$lognormal(f\mu T-\frac{(f\sigma)^2T}{2},(f\sigma)^2T)$. Then calculate the cdf and take the derivative with respect to $f$ to find the maximum.

Comment: just a guess, but probably Kelly criterion can be used here.

Comment: The general solution to this type of problem is given by the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation with the terminal condition that the payoff is $1$ is wealth is above $e$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: Obviously it is optimal to set $f=0$ after reaching $e$.